# 'Procedure or function '...' expects parameter '...', which was not supplied.'

Tags: c#, sql-server

I was developing my project and this error occurred to me:

> "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function' dbo.Bi_medicaoInset 'expects parameter' @ID_interno_disp ', which was not supplied.'"

I have already searched the internet but I can't find anything to help me.

C# code:

```
SqlConnection connString = new SqlConnection ("Data Source = (LocalDb) \\ MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = tupaidb; Integrated Security = True");
                    connString.Open ();
                    
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand ();
command.Connection = connString;
command.CommandText = "[dbo]. [dbo.Bi_medicaoInset]";
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

command.Parameters.Add ("@ID_interno_disp", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters.Add ("@med_hum", SqlDbType.VarChar, (50)). Value = humidity + "%";
command.Parameters.Add ("@med_temp", SqlDbType.VarChar, (50)). Value = temperature + "ºC";
command.Parameters.Add ("@med_lpg", SqlDbType.VarChar, (50)). Value = lpgGas + "%";
command.Parameters.Add ("@med_co", SqlDbType.VarChar, (50)). Value = monoCarbo + "%";
command.Parameters.Add ("@med_fumo", SqlDbType.VarChar, (50)). Value = smoke + "%";
command.ExecuteNonQuery ();
connString.Close ();
```

Stored Procedure:

```
USE [tupaidb]
GO
/ ****** Object: StoredProcedure [dbo]. [Dbo.Bi_medicaoInset] Script Date: 5/18/2021 08:29:17 ****** /
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo]. [Dbo.Bi_medicaoInset]
    @ID_interno_disp int,
    @med_hum Varchar (50),
    @med_temp Varchar (50),
    @med_lpg Varchar (50),
    @med_co Varchar (50),
    @med_fumo Varchar (50)
AT
BEGIN
    insert into Bi_medicao (ID_interno_disp, med_hum, med_temp, med_lpg, med_co, med_fumo)
    values ​​(@ ID_interno_disp, @ med_hum, @ med_temp, @ med_lpg, @ med_co, @ med_fumo)
END
```

I want the value of the column "ID_interno_disp" of the table "Bi_dispositivo" to pass to the other table with the same column name.

[image]

Comment: That typically happens when you set the value of a parameter to C# `null` rather than SQL `DBNull.Value`. And I don't know why you have a space between `@` and the param name? It may have no effect but I would remove it all the same.

Comment: I have no spaces in the code was my mistake when copying!

Comment: observation; there's something very wrong with your DB layout if you have objects in the `dbo` schema *called* `dbo.Something`

Comment: `I want the value of the column "ID_interno_disp" of the table "Bi_dispositivo" to pass to the other table with the same column name!` You need to do that yourself. It isn't magic. The program can't guess what ID you expect it to be.

Comment: I'd also argue that storing `%` at the end of everything is problematic. `%` feels like a _display_ concern not a _storage_ concern. By storing % there you are making it more expensive to store and more expensive to query. Also, `(50)` should be 50.

Comment: `@ ID_interno_disp, @ med_hum, @ med_temp, @ med_lpg, @ med_co, @ med_fumo)` Style wise, I'd encourage you to remove those spaces after `@`.

Comment: The short term answer to your immediate question is to use `command.Parameters.Add ("@ID_interno_disp", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be ID_interno_disp column is set as identity column.
In that case there is no need to pass paramater for this column at all.
so remove parameter for it.
Add below after Insert statement

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS 'Identity'

--this will return identity value inserted only within the current scope

SELECT @@IDENTITY AS 'Identity'; 

--this is not limited to a specific scope
```

This will give you the autoincremented Id for the latest record.
And then you can use this id to insert in to other table Bi_dispositivo

Answer (score 2):

1. take out the spaces
2. supply a value (parameters with a `null` value *are not sent*)

so:

```cs
command.CommandText = "[dbo].[dbo.Bi_medicaoInset]";
// ...
command.Parameters.Add("@ID_interno_disp", SqlDbType.Int).Value = somethingHere;
```

You may also find it a *lot* easier to use tools like Dapper, which simplify the ADO.NET API:

```cs
using var conn = new SqlConnection ("...");
conn.Execute("[dbo].[dbo.Bi_medicaoInset]",
    new { ID_interno_disp = whatever,
       med_hum = humidity + "%",
       med_temp = temperature + "ºC",
       med_lpg = lpgGas + "%",
       med_co = monoCarbo + "%",
       med_fumo = smoke + "%"
    });
```

Comment: This is a foreign key because the value that will appear there is another column in the other table: /

Comment: @Ronald you still have to provide a value, even if DBNull, unless you define the parameter as output only.

Comment: @Ronald (or can we just call you Pedro? we've seen variants of this question multiple times over the last few days) it isn't clear to me what relevance your foreign key comment has; there is a parameter: you need to supply a value or it isn't sent; that value could be `DBNull.Value` if you want to send a database `null`

Comment: @Ronald stored procedures have no foreign keys. You have to provide a value for all parameters, if that's an explicit `null`.

Comment: I apologize if you are not understanding very well, I will explain, my program has two tables one of them called "Bi_medicao" and the other "Bi_dispositivo"
I created a primary key in the "Bi_device" table
called "ID_interno_disp" this primary key automatically assigns its value and I want this value to be passed to the other table "Bi_medicao" for the column "ID_interno_disp" I don't want the value to be null!

Comment: @Ronald so what value do you want it to be? it needs to come from somewhere, since you need to pass it to `[dbo.Bi_medicaoInset]`; if it was your intent to capture the new identity/primary-key value from a row you inserted *just before this*, then: you need to add code to capture that value - perhaps using the `OUTPUT` clause (depending on your server version; other options include `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and `@@IDENTITY`)

Comment: @Ronald I'm not sure what you want me to do with that; I can't tell you what the value is meant to be - only you can do that; somewhere in your code, you need to *get the correct `ID_interno_disp`* value, perhaps via the `disp_mac`, or perhaps via some other knowledge; I can't tell you what the correct value is. I can take guesses; is it 42? But ultimately that is a separate question: the question *here* is about a missing parameter - we've answered that.